# How to add secret token to all projects of particular gitlab group?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I am trying to setup CI/CD and I need to add "Secret Token" to all the projects of a particular gitlab group. I am adding **webhooks** using **python-gitlab** API.

> Is there a way to also add "Secret Token" using **python-gitlab**? or Is there a way in gitlab itself to update the "Secret Token" of all projects?

[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. This is already explained [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/7063)